# Error 409. Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

Tags: python, telegram-bot

`api.telegram.org/bot/getWebhookInfo` --> `{"ok":true,"result":"url":"","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0}}`

`api.telegram.org/bot/getUpdates` --> `{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}`

**I get these answers from API. How to fix them?**

Answer (score 1):

At each given time only one process may call `getUpdates`. You apparently have another process doing that.

Comment: I don't have another process. I've revoked token. It's not helping